# Unable to create an RDD from an existing RDD - Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a new RDD from an existing RDD.

1. Intilaize an Array

   ```
   scala> var a1 = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
   a1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
   ```
2. Create the first RDD

   ```
   scala> var r1 = sc.parallelize(a1)
   r1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <
   console>:26
   ```
3. Create the 2nd RDD - It fails with the following error.

   ```
   scala> var newrdd = sc.parallelize(r1.map(data=>(data*2)))
   <console>:26: error: type mismatch;
   found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
   required: Seq[?]
   Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
          var newrdd = sc.parallelize(r1.map(data=>(data*2)))
                                     ^
   ```

But still the first array can be used to create another RDD. But it is not creating an RDD from an existing RDD.

```
scala> var newrdd = sc.parallelize(a1.map(data=>(data*2)))
newrdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize
at <console>:26
```

Do you have any idea, What is the problem with this approach?

Or how I can create an RDD from an existing RDD?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: But why do you have to parallelize again, r1 is already a RDD you can just apply transformation and it returns RDD, Just use `var newrdd = r1.map(data=>(data*2))`

Comment: Thanks. I am a beginner and currently following a tutorial. From there I found this example. However, It seems like your argument is valid may be this is a mistake of the tutor.

Comment: Update: Tutor told me this is a mistake of him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `parallelize` method is:

```scala
def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T]
```

,so you **cannot** pass a `RDD` as a parameter directly.

If you want to *create an RDD from an existing RDD*, you can use the methods defined for `RDD`. For example,

```
val newrdd = r1.map(data => data * 2)
```

Or simply, `r1.map(_ * 2)`.